# How decides Typo3 Neos which Settings.yaml to choose?

Tags: typo3-flow, neoscms

i use one Neos installation for multiple domains with different content.
duplicating the package TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org, removing the node-identifier and doing some replacements brought me nearby everything i need.

But only the first Settings.yaml found in Packages/Sites/ seems to be parsed. All changes to the Settings.yaml found in other packages (Test1 and Test2 in the following example) are ignored.

Packages/Sites/TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org/Configuration/Settings.yaml

```
TYPO3:
  Form:
    yamlPersistenceManager:
      savePath: 'resource://TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org/Private/Form/'
```

Packages/Sites/UDF.Test1/Configuration/Settings.yaml

```
TYPO3:
  Form:
    yamlPersistenceManager:
      savePath: 'resource://UDF.Test1/Private/Form/'
```

Packages/Sites/UDF.Test2/Configuration/Settings.yaml

```
TYPO3:
  Form:
    yamlPersistenceManager:
      savePath: 'resource://UDF.Test2/Private/Form/'
```

When i delete the first Settings.yaml (Packages/Sites/UDF.Test2/Configuration/Settings.yaml), the next Setting.yaml in alphabetical order (Packages/Sites/UDF.Test1/Configuration/Settings.yaml) is used for all 3 site packages. When i also delete this file, the Settings.yaml from UDF.Test2 is used and so on.

would be awesome if somebody can enlighten me. I am new to flow and neos and any help is welcome. RTFM, i know, but as described [here](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Configuration.html) i have to believe, that it should work like i did?

### alternative way?

is it possible not to set the savePath in the site package configuration but in the common settings ./Packages/Application/TYPO3.Form/Configuration/Settings.yaml

I see a {@package} placeholder in

```
### BASE ELEMENTS ###
# NAMING: base class for everything is RENDERABLE
  'TYPO3.Form:Base':
    renderingOptions:
      templatePathPattern: 'resource://{@package}/Private/Form/{@type}.html'
```

but this doesn't work here

```
TYPO3:
  Form:
    yamlPersistenceManager:
      #savePath: '%FLOW_PATH_DATA%Forms/'
      savePath: 'resource://{@package}/Private/Form/'
```

as you see i am not really experienced with this stuff but i am very motivated.

Answer (score 3):

All Settings.yaml are used, but the settings are merged in order of the package loading. 
The loading order of packages again is based on their dependencies.
All three packages probably have the same dependencies so they are loaded one after the other (would need to check with which ordering), so third Settings.yaml is loaded, then second Settings.yaml is loaded and overwrites the third, then the first is loaded and again overwrites the second. Every setting path can only be set once, that's why.

In any case what you are trying to archive probably won't work. This is one of the things we have to fix (site package dependent configuration).

A possible workaround is either using a common package with the form configuration and just set the savePath to this package or using diferent subcontexts (like Production/Domain1 Production/Domain2) and setting this setting different per subcontext, then you could define the subcontext by domain (as the sites are triggered by domain anyway).

Comment: Thx so far, Kitsunet... i needed to fix my system, now i will try to go further...

Your first possible workaround is not working for me, because i need different form settings (labels and addresses) for each site package. If i didn't missunderstood you, this behaviour is the actual one? The common package with the form configuration comply to ./Packages/Application/TYPO3.Form/Configuration/Settings.yaml?

Comment: About using different subcontexts i don't really understand, what to do. Would you kindly post me a link with further informations? Especially about defining the subcontext by domain and how the sites are triggered.

Comment: Can i solve the task by checking the loading order of the packages? Maybe i have the same dependencies on all site packages because i cloned the package TYPO3.NeosDemoTypo3Org for my site packages? 
But for every domain i only need to load ONE site package so the settings would not be overwritten.The dependencies are configured in the composer manifests as descriped [here](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/PackageManagement.html#loading-order)? Need to dig into it...

Comment: please have a look on my **alternative way** in my question as it is not possible to format code in comments?

Comment: Unfortunately those variables are only replaced in the template context. I think you could probably extend the \TYPO3\Form\Persistence\YamlPersistenceManager to accept additional information. To solve it with sub  context see also the information here: [link](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Bootstrapping.html#custom-contexts) and [link](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Configuration.html#file-locations)